# Android Studio + Volley = NoClassDefFound?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

Well, I decided to try out the Volley networking library for Android and the new Android Studio IDE at the same time.. However, I'm running into some problems.

I built volley.jar, copied it into my libs folder for a new project, edited build.gradle to include volley, and setup a static ImageLoader and RequestQueue in my main activity.  However, when I load the app onto an emulator (4.2), I end up getting

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
```

when invoking Volley as follows:

```
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

Gradle edits to support the library:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
}
```

Anyone mind pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: +1 for the question. I simply jumped back to Eclipse after about an hour of mind numbing research... failed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182957/exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-common-accountp)

Found the fix here.

Basically, open a command prompt (or terminal) and navigate to your project directory.  Use the following command on Windows:

For **Windows** users:
gradlew.bat clean

And for **mac** users type: ./gradlew clean

Then reload Android Studio and try again!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure your method works too, but I didn't even mess around with the gradle build stuff.
Instead, I simply copied the com folder into my java src folder in Android Studio. It works for Eclipse too.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error trying to run an application with volley

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
```

in IntelliJ.

I simply had to go into **File** >> **Project** Structure (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)

to the volley module, then the associated facet and check the checkbox 'Library module' to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

- Open "File -> Project Structure"
- Click "Project Settings -> Modules"
- Click "Add -> Import Module"
- Select Volley directory on your computer that you already cloned the Volley Project via "git clone"
- After adding Volley as a library project/module, check if there is a cyclic dependency reference to your main project under "Modules -> Volley -> Dependencies", delete it if available
- Check if Volley module is added to your main Project Module under "Modules -> Your Projects Main Module -> Dependencies", if there is no depencency on there, click "Add -> Module Depencency"
- After adding Volley depencency, move to "Up" if needed. I'm not sure if it's necessary.
- Click "Project Settings -> Facets -> Volley" tick the checkbox named "Library module", to make your volley module not to run standalone but run like a module with your Project's Main module