# Cannot access class from aar

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I have been stuck for the past 2 days now. I want to import my own aar in one of my sample apps and then use it. I can not access the classes inside the aar and get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` error.

Now since this is a common problem, I have tried the below so far,after reading each and every related question:

1) Importing the aar by going to : `File -> New-> New Module -> Import .JAR/.AAR`
and then adding `compile project(':Name-Of-Your-Project')` to the gradle.

2) Using the maven plugin and pushing the aar to the local maven repo by using gradle install and then reffering to the local repo aar in my gradle.

```
compile ('com.rsa.mobile.sdk.android:authsdk:3.6.0-SNAPSHOT:debug@aar'){
      //  transitive=true
    }
```

Note: If I uncomment the transitive=true, i get the below exception while installing the application:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

3) Rebuilding and cleaning the project as suggested in a lot of answers.

4) The only one thing which didnt work out was by putting the aar in a directory and then reffering it like `compile(name:'Name-Of-Your-Project', ext:'aar')` , after adding

```
flatDir {
      dirs 'libs'
        }
```

to the repo.
I dont think the 4th point should matter as the correct way now is as mentioned in point 1 above, but just wanted to put it out.

Can someone please help. It looks like a trivial issue but I have already wasted around 2 days.

Comment: Is your classes are obfuscated?

Comment: No they are not, I have used the same aar before with different sample apps. This is the first time I am facing this problem.

Comment: As per your exception, your method count is more than 64K; So you should use `multidex`. [Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) is the detail.

Comment: I did try that, that dint work out as it resulted in java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded android exception. Anyways its a very small aar, there is no way the method count is that much, the problem is somewhere else I guess.

Comment: For that, you have to use `incremental` and `javaMaxHeapSize` of `dexOptions` in your gradle file. Please check the gradle options.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the exception the below code can solve the problem. Add it in the  application gradle.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
dexOptions { 
        // FOR GC overhead 
          incremental true 
          javaMaxHeapSize "4g" 
    }
}
```

Comment: After doing this I get an exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley. This was not coming before. I already have compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0' in my gradle.

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002636/android-studio-volley-noclassdeffound).It may help you.