# Air Native Extension can't find Volley java class, NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, actionscript-3, air, air-native-extension

So I'm trying to create Air Native extension that will get data from server in the background and then display notification. I'm already tried it on normal android application and it worked.

But when I try to make it as ANE it didn't work because somehow the code can't find volley (anything else is fine, including the background service)

Logcat result:

```
--------- beginning of crash
03-27 10:46:23.640  3680  3680 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 10:46:23.640  3680  3680 E AndroidRuntime: Process: air.bg, PID: 3680
03-27 10:46:23.640  3680  3680 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/android/volley/toolbox/Volley;
03-27 10:46:23.640  3680  3680 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.company.backgroundprocess.JobSchedulerService.onStartJob(JobSchedulerService.java:54)
```

And here is the JobScheduler.java:

```
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
    parameters = jobParameters;

    settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    unixTimeLastNotificationOnDevice = settings.getLong("lastNotificationTime", System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    //Line 54 bellow
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    mJobHandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(mJobHandler, 1, jobParameters));
    return true;
}
```

And that line caused error, which actually worked in normal android application, but unfortunately not in ANE

So I tried analyze the .apk with Android Studio and I find it included, which [you can see on my screenshot here](https://snag.gy/Y8Qz0C.jpg). And it's weird since the code can't find it.

Additional information, platform.xml I used:

```
<platform xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/13.0">
    <packagedDependencies>
        <packagedDependency>support-compat-26.1.0-sources.jar</packagedDependency>
        <packagedDependency>volley-1.1.0-sources.jar</packagedDependency>
    </packagedDependencies>
</platform>
```

Comment: maven or gradle ?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't know what what AirSDK used to compile the flash project to apk. 
But about the .jar dependency I got it from maven repository. 
And when I'm testing it using normal android application, I'm using gradle to build the .apk

Comment: Fine, look at my answer. Maybe, it will help you

Comment: When you are packaging your ANE with adt are you correctly setting the platform options to your platform.xml for the android implementation?

Comment: @Michael I'm packaging my ane like this: `adt -package -target ane com.company.BackgroundJob.ane .\extension.xml -swc .\BackgroundJobAPI.swc -platform Android-ARM -platformoptions .\platform.xml -C .\Android . -platform Android-x86 -platformoptions .\platform.xml -C .\Android .` Is there something wrong with how I do it?

Comment: Are you sure the jar is in your Android dir? Also are you sure the `sources` jar is the one you want to package?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Maven or Gradle ?
For Gradle check if you have

`dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
}`

for Maven check if you have

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
    <version>r6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.android.volley</groupId>
        <artifactId>volley</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.mcxiaoke.volley</groupId>
        <artifactId>library</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In your ecplise double check if someother jar is conflicting `com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.class` (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and search with Volley). If so, resolve the dependencies.

Open a command prompt (or terminal) and navigate to your project directory.
Run :

```
gradlew.bat clean
```

Reload Android Studio

References [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002636/android-studio-volley-noclassdeffound/#17002863)