# Volley ClassNotFoundException com.android.volley.Response$Listener

Tags: android, android-volley, noclassdeffounderror

I've written a module for network APIs in order to import it in 2 apps. In this module I use volley. The first time that I've generated the module.aar and imported it in other project, it work. Now, I've runtime error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/android/volley/Response$Listener;
```

I've:

- clean app and module through ./gradlew clean
- added in proguard module file

  -keep class com.android.volley.Response { *; }
  -keepclassmembers class com.android.volley.Response { *; }
  -keepclassmembers class com.android.volley.Response$Listener { *; }
  -keep class com.android.volley.Response$Listener { *; }
- disabled proguard in debug config mode for network module

Nothing of this is good, I still receive NoClassDefFoundError when initialize Volley.

The gradle file of module is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
}

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug{
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: try the method mentioned in the accepted answer maybe it helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002636/android-studio-volley-noclassdeffound/

Comment: did you use volley dependency in Gradel file

Comment: @user3816569 already tried

Comment: @farhana obviously

Comment: [have you tried this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326929/how-to-include-dependence-library-when-export-aar-file)