# AccountPicker removed from PlayServices?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-account

After updating google ads services to version 8.1.0  I can't use AccountPicker to get user email. 
before i use
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'` and AccountPicker works.

I want to use latest library, but after updating:
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'`
I have error Cannot resolve 'AccountPicker'
How to import AccountPicker?

Comment: I tried it with `8.1.0`, it works for me. Have you tried to do `import com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker;`  manually in your java files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182957/exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-common-accountp)

Answer (score 0):

If you use android studio, then this can be relevant (you have to do a clean & build (which AS doesn't truly do right now)): [Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182957/exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-common-accountp)