# Android import import com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker error

Tags: android, android-account

I am trying to implement an account picker with the following:

```
Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[]{"com.google"}, false, null, null, null, null);

startActivityForResult(intent, 1111);
```

but I get error on import and in the android part of 
 import com.google.**android**.gms.common.AccountPicker

How can I fix this?

in build Gradle I have

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
```

}

is it the same as the article here?

[Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182957/exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-common-accountp)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have missed the [setup](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) step that is adding `GooglePlayService` to your `build.gradle`.

In your `build.gradle` file inside your application module directory, add a new build rule under dependencies for the latest version of play-services:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

If you only need `AccountPicker`:

1- you can replace above line with:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0'
```

So you don't need to compile complete gms and you don't face 65,536 methods problem.

2- You don't need to add google play service for picking account. Use [newChoosAccountIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#newChooseAccountIntent(android.accounts.Account,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.accounts.Account%3E,%20java.lang.String[],%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20android.os.Bundle)) method available in `AccountManager` class.